# ActionScript Binding Array Objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, binding

i would like to update the numbers i've added to an array from variables, when those variables change.  is it possible change these variables and have the array update automatically?

```
var first:Number = 1;
var second:Number = 2;

var myArray:Array = new Array(first, second);

first = 3;
second = 4;

trace(myArray) //outputs 1,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing a primitive type ( Number ), use an Object to wrap Number. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
var first:Object = { value: 1 };
var second:Object = { value: 2 };

var array:Array = [ first, second ];

first.value = 3;
second.value = 4;
```